# How To Pass Object Parameter to Javascript Function

Tags: javascript

There have been many post about passing parameters into Javascript but it seems none has solved my issue here. Therefore, I hope you can help me with this.

I have an object of string (actually its a time) but it seems that only integers are allowed to be passed into the function

Could it be a syntax problem?

```
displayBidder += "<button class='btn'><a href='javascript:void(null);' onClick='decline(" + obj.Data[i].jobid + ", " + obj.Data[i].bidtime + ") '>Decline</a></button>"

function decline(jobid, time){

    alert(time);

}

$("#display").html(displayBidder);
```

Comment: This is a whole lot cleaner if you don't use onclick=xxx, but rather use an event listener.

Comment: JavaScript accepts any type as a function argument.  It's something wrong with your code.

Comment: wats the value in `obj.Data[i].jobid`, `obj.Data[i].bidtime`. Show some more code..

Answer (score 0):

> I have an object of string (actually its a time) but it seems that only integers are allowed to be passed into the function

No. But numbers (and booleans, null and undefined) are the only primitives that will yield an `eval`uable value for themselves if they are stringified. Do a `console.log(displayBidder)` to see what html you are producing. If the ids are numbers it will become

```
<button … onClick='decline(1, 2) '>Decline</button>
```

but if they're strings it will become

```
<button … onClick='decline(one, two) '>Decline</button>
```

(which are variables!) and if you used (non-array) objects it would even be

```
<button … onClick='decline([object Object], [object Object]) '>Decline</button>
```

That means you need to serialize the values properly so that they can be interpreted. `JSON.stringify` could do that, but there's a much better solution:

Use proper event handlers. Inline event attributes are disapproved, especially if created by js. Instead, use

```
$("#display")
  .html(displayBidder)
  .append($("<button class='btn'>Decline</button>").on("click", /*(function(i) {
       return*/ function(event) {
           alert( obj.Data[i].jobid );
           // and do whatever you want
       }/*;
   })(i)*/));
```

<sub>Uncomment the IEFE if you use this snippet in a loop and `i` has changed when the handler is executed. See [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example) for an explanation</sub>